# Add title to df before Column names

Tags: python, pandas, title

I fill df with rows of data and each column has a name/title. Is it possible to append or somehow add just 1 row with title before column names, like in the attached picture.

[image]

Comment: what attached picture?

Comment: I think you meant when you export it to excel, no? .. if this is what you want, there is a parameter for that called `skiprows`.

Comment: No, I use skiprows when I import df to exclude unnecessary data. I need to add title row before I export to excel file. Before column names.